# How to match a pattern against an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, search

we have `$.inArray(searchString, array)` function in jQuery, but this will look for the exact match of the string in the values present in the array. But how to check the string in the array like `indexOf`?

For e.g., Let us take the string "mark_zuck" and if the array looks like this, `["mark", "sheryl", "zuck"]`. We can do this by using a loop comparing each value in array with the given string like,

```
for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    searchString.indexOf(array[i]);
}
```

I'm looking for a better way to implement this. Please help.

Comment: @Archer What do you mean by "parse the array"?

Comment: I deleted my comments as it turns out I was wrong!  atinder has posted a nearly correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.filter(function(a){
  return searchString.indexOf(a) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: It should be `return  searchString.indexOf(a) !== -1;`

Comment: @Archer @ atinder Hey, can you take a look of the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/udhayakumar/3v3288s6/. Because it is returning  ["sheryl", "zuck"] instead of  ["mark", "zuck"]. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you've highlighted the reason you need `!== -1` at the end.  atinder updated the answer to include it, so try what he has above now.

Comment: @Archer Oops, I didn't notice that. Sorry and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.some also

```
var monthNames = ["mark", "sheryl", "zuck"];
var chk = 'mark_zuck';

var test = monthNames.some(function(e) {    
   return chk.indexOf(e);
});
console.log(test);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/haqk2snr/